# switch case from subquery sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume that I have 6 tables: `Users, Customers, Providers` (each user must be or customer or provider), `Requests, Offers, Booking`.

Each customer can publish new request, and each provider can make an offer for any request, if the customer want he can make booking for one of the offer (each request may have at most one booking).

I want to crate query that shows for each request its status, if there is no offer for this request, show 'Waiting for offer', if there at least one request for this request but there is no booking show 'Waiting for booking', and if there booking for this request show 'closed'.

At first I tried:

```
SELECT 
    R.RequestID, O.OfferID, B.OfferID,
    CASE 
       WHEN O.OfferID IS NULL THEN 'Waiting for offer'
       WHEN O.OfferID IS NOT NULL AND B.OfferID IS NULL THEN 'Waiting for booking'
       WHEN B.OfferID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Closed'
    END AS Status
FROM
    Requests AS R 
LEFT JOIN 
    Offers AS O ON O.RequestID = R.RequestID 
LEFT JOIN 
    Bookings AS B ON B.OfferID = O.OfferID
```

Results:

[this the results of this query, I added the columns offerID and BookingID To make it more understandable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61zU3.png)

But of course that's obviously not working, because it returns the booking and all the offers for each request, and for each offer its show 'Waiting for booking' or 'Closed'.

For this example the output for requestID '300' Should appear just once, with status 'closed'.

I know that I need to use in subquery for each request and check if there any offer and if so check if there booking for this request, but I don't find the way to check this checks on the subquery, is there way or maybe switch case or if else for this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I edited the post and added a picture of the query result, and explaining what the output should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you don't want to see the booking data if closed, and in that case you want to see only the closed status.  I think you need two queries with a union to get the results you want. Maybe something like this.  Hope it helps.

```
SELECT 
    R.RequestID, O.OfferID, B.OfferID,
    CASE 
       WHEN O.OfferID IS NULL THEN 'Waiting for offer'
       WHEN O.OfferID IS NOT NULL AND B.OfferID IS NULL THEN 'Waiting for booking'
       WHEN B.OfferID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Closed'
    END AS Status
FROM
    Requests AS R 
LEFT JOIN 
    Offers AS O ON O.RequestID = R.RequestID 
LEFT JOIN 
    Bookings AS B ON B.OfferID = O.OfferID
where B.OfferID IS NOT NULL -- where request is closed only
UNION 
SELECT 
    R.RequestID, O.OfferID, B.OfferID,
    CASE 
       WHEN O.OfferID IS NULL THEN 'Waiting for offer'
       WHEN O.OfferID IS NOT NULL AND B.OfferID IS NULL THEN 'Waiting for booking'
       WHEN B.OfferID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Closed'
    END AS Status
FROM
    Requests AS R 
LEFT JOIN 
    Offers AS O ON O.RequestID = R.RequestID 
LEFT JOIN 
    Bookings AS B ON B.OfferID = O.OfferID
where R.requestid not in (

select requestid from requests R
LEFT JOIN 
    Offers AS O ON O.RequestID = R.RequestID 
LEFT JOIN 
    Bookings AS B ON B.OfferID = O.OfferID
where B.OfferID IS NULL

)  -- where request is not closed only
```

Comment: thanks for your helping,  the first table in your query returns all the request that their status 'closed' well, but I need also the requests with status 'Waiting for offer' and requests with status 'Waiting for booking', and the second tables not do that.
I continued with your idea and added table (with UNION that return all the requests with status 'Waiting for offer' ), now I nedd to add table that return the requests with offers but without any bookings that should have status 'Waiting for booking'

Comment: I see. I think you can follow the same idea and just add another query.  So 2 unions, 3 queries altogether with different filtering for each.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your idea of using in Union has resolved my query. I am attaching my solution, which is based and similar to what you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Attached solution, based on the solution of jpock76.

```
    SELECT 
        R.RequestID, O.OfferID, B.OfferID, 'Waiting for offer' as 'status'
    FROM
        Requests AS R 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Offers AS O ON O.RequestID = R.RequestID 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Bookings AS B ON B.OfferID = O.OfferID
    where R.requestid in (
        select R.requestid from requests R
        LEFT JOIN 
            Offers AS O ON O.RequestID = R.RequestID 
        LEFT JOIN 
            Bookings AS B ON B.OfferID = O.OfferID
        where O.OfferID IS NULL
        )  -- where request is not getting any offer
UNION 
    SELECT 
        R.RequestID, O.OfferID, B.OfferID, 'Waiting for Booking' as 'status'
    FROM
        Requests AS R 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Offers AS O ON O.RequestID = R.RequestID 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Bookings AS B ON B.OfferID = O.OfferID
    where O.OfferID IS NOT NULL AND R.requestid NOT IN (
        SELECT R.RequestID
        FROM Requests AS R 
        LEFT JOIN 
            Offers AS O ON O.RequestID = R.RequestID 
        LEFT JOIN 
            Bookings AS B ON B.OfferID = O.OfferID
        WHERE B.OfferID IS NOT NULL)  -- where there offer but not booking
UNION
    (SELECT 
        R.RequestID, O.OfferID, B.OfferID, 'Closed' AS 'Status'
    FROM
        Requests AS R 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Offers AS O ON O.RequestID = R.RequestID 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Bookings AS B ON B.OfferID = O.OfferID
    WHERE B.OfferID IS NOT NULL) -- where request is closed only
ORDER BY R.requestid
```